# How to solve more than one copy of react in a custom component library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-hooks

I have two projects, the first one is the main application and the second one is a custom component library, both in react. Main application uses custom component library by `npm link` command.

However, using custom hooks from custom component library in the main application violated hook rules because there were 2 different react instances. To solve this problem I moved `react` and `react-dom` to `peerDependencies` in package.json of custom component library and added below lines to webpack.config.js of custom component library.

```
module.exports = {
...
externals: {
        'react': {
            commonjs: 'react',
            commonjs2: 'react'
        },
        'react-dom': {
            commonjs: 'react-dom',
            commonjs2: 'react-dom'
        }
    }
...
}
```

Finally, I removed node_modules and run `npm i` again in the custom component library. However, I cannot build the library, it gives the below error build phase.

```
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 1:0-48 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/jsx-runtime' in 'path\to\src'
```

What am I missing in this configuration?

Note: I still have app.tsx and index.tsx in the custom component library.

webpack.config.js of custom component library

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

// Not used since this is a component library, not removed for possible future use
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const host = "localhost" || require('os').hostname().toLowerCase()

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.tsx"),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: { // Not used since this is a component library, not removed for possible future use
        host: host,
        port: port,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        open: true,
        static: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
                use: ['file-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                        }
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
                        plugins: ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import", "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
            favicon: path.join(__dirname, "public", "favicon.ico"),
            manifest: path.join(__dirname, "public", "manifest.json"),
            title: 'Development',
        }),
    ],
    externals: {
        'react': {
            commonjs: 'react',
            commonjs2: 'react'
        },
        'react-dom': {
            commonjs: 'react-dom',
            commonjs2: 'react-dom'
        }
    }
}
```

package.json of custom component library

```
{
  "name": "@optimaze-core/common-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.7.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.36",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.33",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.10",
    "antd": "^4.16.13",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "start": "webpack serve --open",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "sass": "^1.43.4",
    "sass-loader": "^12.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "webpack": "^5.60.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: what version of react are you on?

Comment: are you linking the components locally?

Comment: react version: 17.0.2

Comment: yes, I am linking components locally. I first run npm link in component library and then go to main application directory and npm link "custom-library"

Comment: You could link react so that it only looks at one version. Do you get this problem deployed to npm or just locally? if you run npm install and use the version on npm does it work?

Comment: I get it just locally. I first remove node_modules in the component library and then run "npm i" but nothing changes. What do you mean by "use the version on npm does it work"? I thought I succeeded in linking react by moving its dependency to peerDependencies in package.json of component library. Is there another way to link react in the component library?

Comment: Deployed is the project going to be using the lib from NPM? Our deploy scripts use the published version of our packages. If this is a local only issue you could do something like 


```
cd node_modules/react-dom 

yarn link

cd ..

cd node_modules/react 

yarn link
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd node_modules/react-dom
yarn link 
cd .. 
cd node_modules/react
yarn link
```

Locally, you could link your app's node modules for react and react-dom so it is only using one version.